# JavaScript upload more files one by one

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I have wrote this javascript code to upload files. The problem is it uploads all the files at the same time. I want to upload them one by one. I have been trying to do it for three hours.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':file').change(function() {
        $("#modsform").hide();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            var file = this.files[i];
            showFile(file, i);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
            var file = this.files[i];
            sendFile(file, i);
        }
    });
});
```

full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/yhq83r6o/3/

Comment: So than you need to not use a for loop and use a queue, when the first is done, pick the next one from the list and upload that.

Comment: You are only uploading one file at a time. Each file will go in it's own request What is the higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @epascarello I can do a list of all files to upload, but then I'll need to run sendFile() for each file in the list so it's the same.